# Jquery Mobile button looses height when innerhtml is replaced

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, innerhtml

When I use javascript to change the innerhtml of a button, the button looses the padding above and below the text, but retains the padding on the sides.
This is the code I use:

```
document.getElementById("NextBtn").innerHTML="Finish";
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Can you show the HTML and style for your button?

Comment: I've never used innerHTML on a button. I think I use value. Am I way off here?

Comment: `.value` had the same effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With jQuery widgets you can normally target the `.ui-btn-text` element that will be a descendant of the original element. For instance here is the HTML markup for an initialized button widget from the jQuery Mobile framework:

```
<a data-role="button" href="#" data-theme="c" id="test-btn" class="ui-btn ui-btn-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-up-c">
    <span class="ui-btn-inner ui-btn-corner-all">
        <span class="ui-btn-text">Click Me (0)</span>
    </span>
</a>
```

Notice the text is inside the `span.ui-btn-text` element. Knowing this we can target that element to update the text:

```
$('#test-btn').find('.ui-btn-text').text('New Text!');
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/qp3uF/

### Update

Since there are several types of buttons you could be talking about, here is how to update the text for each:

```
//<a>
$('a').find('.ui-btn-text').text('New Text');

//<input type="button" /> and <input type="submit" />
$('input[type="button"], input[type="submit"]').val('New Text').prev('.ui-btn-inner').children('.ui-btn-text').text('New Text');

//<button>
$('button').prev('.ui-btn-inner').children('.ui-btn-text').text('New Text');
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/qp3uF/2/

Comment: The html for my button is:    `<a href="" data-role="button" id="NextBtn" onClick="next()">Next</a>` and I tried adding: `$('#NextBtn').find('.ui-btn-text').text('Finish');` where before I had `document.getElementById("NextBtn").innerHTML="Finish";`.  It still replaced the text correctly, but the formatting issue was still there.

Comment: @redleaf It works for me in the demos I posted. Do my demos work for you as well?

Comment: Sorry, it was an error on my part - it works perfectly now! Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried refreshing the button after you manipulate it?

Something like this:

```
$('[type="submit"]').button('refresh');
```

[Link to jQuery Mobile Docs](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0.1/docs/buttons/buttons-methods.html)

Comment: Trying to refresh the button results in this error: `Uncaught cannot call methods on button prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'refresh'`: http://jsfiddle.net/qp3uF/3/. If you remove `'refresh'` to initialize the widget, nothing happens: http://jsfiddle.net/qp3uF/4/

Comment: I had assumed that the question was about a form button, which is what the refresh would work for. Link based buttons don't use the refresh function. My bad for assuming.